# Forward an element of a tuple

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, metaprogramming, perfect-forwarding

Consider the following code:

```
template <unsigned int Index, class Tuple, class Type = /* Something1 */>
Type forward(Tuple&& tuple)
{
    return /* Something2 */;
}
```

I would like to find what is the correct syntax of `/* Something1 */` and `/* Something2 */` in order to forward the element specified by `Index` of the input `tuple`. I know that other conceptions/syntax would be available, but in order to understand correctly how things work in such a context (consider this as *an academic exercice*), I would like an answer that satisfy the following conditions:

- no overload for different cases: there will be only one templated function `forward`
- no change except `/* Something1 */` and `/* Something2 */` (and maybe on the return type if it should be `Type&&` instead of `Type`)
- metaprogramming crazyness, `decltype` and `std::declval` are accepted

For example, if `Tuple = std::tuple<char, int, double>`, then `forward<2>(tuple)` should forward the third element (if the tuple is passed as a const reference, then the function should return a const reference to the `double`).

Comment: Could you clarify if in your example you want `Type` to be `double` or `double&&`?  I see that your question actually asks this question, but only you can design your API.  Perhaps you could tell us what you want this API to do.

Comment: @Howard: Shouldn't it be `double` or `double&` for the lvalue `tuple`?

Comment: @DieterLücking : this is not a homework, I am working in supercomputing... this is a "I want to be sure to understand what's happening here and the best way to do this is to use an academic exercice approach"

Comment: If `Tuple` is `std::tuple<char, int, double>`, then the argument is an rvalue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on what you want to achieve with that function. In general it is a bad idea to propagate rvalue-ness to members. However, there is already an implementation in the standard library. You can use `std::get` in the following way:

```
template <
    std::size_t Index,
    typename Tuple,
    typename Type = decltype(std::get<Index>(std::declval<Tuple>()))>
auto forward(Tuple&& tuple) -> Type
{
    return std::get<Index>(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple));
}
```

Comment: Also note that this makes the function a completely transparent wrapper over `std::get`, and thus kinda pointless: you can just use `std::get<Index>(tuple)` directly on-site.

Comment: `decltype(std::get<Index>(std::declval<Tuple>()))` could be replaced with `typename std::tuple_element<Index, Tuple>::type` (C++11) or `std::tuple_element_t<Index, Tuple>` (C++14).